# Help deciphering an NSString "passing argument ... from distinct Objective-C type warning"

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, constants, compiler-warnings

I am having trouble deciphering a "passing argument ... from distinct Objective-C type warning".

I have a constant string declared as:

```
extern NSString * const URL_1;
```

and defined as:

```
NSString * const URL_1 = @"http://someurl";
```

If I, say, assign that constant to an NSString as follows:

```
NSString *URL = nil;
...
URL = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:URL_1];
```

And pass this NSString as an argument to a function expecting an NSString:

```
ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithURL:URL];
```

Function signature:

```
- (id)initWithURL:(NSString *)URL
```

I receive a warning that I am "passing argument 1 of 'initWithURL': from distinct Objective-C type"

As I understand it NSString objects are immutable once created, and I am assigning the value to the string once upon creation, so I don't understand why the constant nature of URL_1 should cause a problem.

I am sure I am being a donut here and have overlooked something simple! Please could someone help me resolve this warning? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm pretty sure removing the 'const' will kill the issue, but not enough to issue it as an answer.

Comment: Yes I would have thought so too but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Are you sure it's okay that your initWithURL: method takes a string and not an NSURL?

Comment: what does your ViewController initWithURL method look like?

Comment: I know the naming could be better but the function is declared as:
...
- (id)initWithURL:(NSString *)URL
{
    if (self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain]) 
    {
        NSURL *URL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:URL];
...

Coincidentally the last line here throws the same warning as the function call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many methods in the system frameworks that are declared as:

```
- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)anURL;
```

And, of course, `+alloc` is declared as:

```
- (id) alloc;
```

Thus, when the compiler sees:

```
ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithURL:URL];
```

The return type of the allocation is `id` and the compiler is likely seeing the above declaration and that causes the warning.  Now, generally, the compiler would also warn that it found multiple signatures for the selector -- multiple signatures for that particular method name.

If it isn't, it is quite likely because you haven't imported `ViewController.h` into the file that contains the above line of code.

In short, *do not declare a method with the same name as another method that takes a different type of argument.*

Comment: Great thanks bbum, I should've spotted that by the colour that the function call was displayed in.
Changing both function call and variable name to initWithSourceURL and sourceURL respectively resolved the warning.

Comment: Excellent.  I would also recommend changing the method to something like `initWithSourceURLString:` as ending w/URL usually means the parameter is an NSURL*